# Black screen recording games

Tags: integrated-graphics, screen-recorder

Whenever I play a full screen directx game and attempt to screen record, the mouse shows up but the game does not. I'm using Intel HD Graphics 4000 and I'm assuming its a hardware issue, though I'm not sure if different software would fix it. I've tried BBExpress, Microsoft Expression Encoder, and CamStudio.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Update your graphics drivers, then try Fraps and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Do you know any free Fraps alternatives?

Comment: Nope, I use the registered version since it's quite powerful and I really like it.

Comment: Recording full-screen DirectX is actually extremely difficult in technical terms, and the only thing that does it any way successfully is FRAPS.